# Why can Scala compiler not infer Stream type operations?

Tags: scala, stream

Lets say I want to have a `Stream` of squares. A simple way to declare it would be:

```
scala> def squares(n: Int): Stream[Int] = n * n #:: squares(n + 1)
```

But doing so, yields an error:

```
<console>:8: error: overloaded method value * with alternatives:
  (x: Double)Double <and>
  (x: Float)Float <and>
  (x: Long)Long <and>
  (x: Int)Int <and>
  (x: Char)Int <and>
  (x: Short)Int <and>
  (x: Byte)Int
 cannot be applied to (scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int])
       def squares(n: Int): Stream[Int] = n * n #:: squares(n + 1)
                                            ^
```

so, why can't Scala infer the type of `n` which is obviously an `Int`? Can someone please explain what's going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just a precedence issue.  Your expression is being interpreted as `n * (n #:: squares(n + 1))`, which is clearly not well-typed (hence the error).

You need to add parentheses:

```
def squares(n: Int): Stream[Int] = (n * n) #:: squares(n + 1)
```

Incidentally, this isn't an *inference* problem, because the types are known (i.e., `n` is known to be of type `Int`, so it need not be inferred).